# npm Module build failed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

[image]

I have tried to run `npm run watch` but every time it shows this error. Anyone Please help me. Click on the image to view the problem.
Thanks, In advance

Comment: Looks like it's trying to use an npm package that doesnt exist. Have you tried running "npm install"?

Answer (score 0):

Check your error:

> Module build failed: Error: "...." is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command.
>   operable program or batch file.

Run this command in your command prompt:

```
npm install
```